# Different alignment for frame content in beamer

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, positioning

I am searching for a way to align the content of a frame in `beamer`.
I want to have one part of the text of the frame top aligned, while the rest of the page is centered in the middle, as its normally.
Is there a way to archive that without mis-using the `\frametitle` for it?

```
+------------------------------+
|frametitle                    |
| subtitle                     |
+------------------------------+
|my notes (top aligned)        |
|                              |
|                              |
|other notes (middle aligned)  |
|more text   (also at middle)  |
|                              |
|                              |
+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{title}
\framesubtitle{subtitle}
my notes (top aligned)
    \vfill
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item   item 1
        \item   item 2
        \item   item 3
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Looks good so far. I wonder if there is a way to define it more globaly instead of putting it on every single slide. (will accept the answer anyway :), thanks for the help)

Comment: @user2567875: Unless your top-aligned stuff is the same in every frame, it's not obvious how to define it globally. You could, however, define a macro `\newcommand\tnotes[1]{#1\par\vfill\par}` and use `\tnotes{my notes (top aligned)}` to enter top-aligned materials.