# Align part of beamer-slide to top

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

I want to have parts of my beamer slide to be aligned to the top of the slide. The rest should still align automatically to the middle.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{tcolorbox}
align to top
\end{tcolorbox}

align to middle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Like in [Different alignment for frame content in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225588/different-alignment-for-frame-content-in-beamer?rq=1) solution. (If this is a good/right solution). But is it able, to define `tcolorbox` or a new environment such that the `[t]` option is added to the frame and the `\vfill` after the environment (which seems to be the easy part)

Comment: thew simplest way is add to frames, which contain `tcolorbox` option `[t]` and then consider answer for which you provide link. this answer can be improved on the way, as i show (now erased) answer (which you not liked) ...

Comment: This is exactly the solution from the link. I was wondering if it's possible to define a new environment which contains something like `\addtoframe{option}{t}` and of course `\vfill` in the closing part

Comment: maybe, but i don't know if it possible test frame content, if it  contain `tcolorbox` and than change it from `\begin{frame}\frametitle{...} ...` to `\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle{...} ...`. this is not trivial task and i'm curious, if some of "beamer" wizard provide a solution.

Comment: (I believe) One doesn't need to test frame content. The `\begin{mytopcolorbox}...` maybe can set a frame option.

Comment: option `[t]` at start of frame ...  and see, that it is needed when `latex` find `tcolorbox`  is already to late or you fall in loop giving error "sorry capacity is  ...". anyway, wait on experts for beamer what they will say :-)

Answer (score 1):

**edit:**

reading  [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) answer gives me the following idea:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcommand\mytcolorbox[1]{%
    \framesubtitle{\medskip%
        \centerline{\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth]
                    #1
                    \end{tcolorbox}}}
                        }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\mytcolorbox{align to top}
align to middle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title}
align to middle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

*pros:* simple in working :-)

*cons:* yin the same time you can't use `\framesubtitle`, it will be overwritten by `\mytcolorbox`

[image]

Comment: The global alignment should still be middle. Only if there is a tcolorbox, it and only it, should be aligned to the top (Actually your code doesn't produce this output ;) )

Comment: well, than you should wait on better answer (i will erase mine soon) ... the simplest solution is write option `[t]` when necessary, but you are not wiling to do this ... :-(

Comment: good idea!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could make the `tcolorbox` ride piggy back of the frametitle:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

{
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    align to top
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
\begin{frame}{Title}
align to middle
\end{frame}
}

{
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    align to top
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
\begin{frame}{\mbox{}}
align to middle
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

Drawback: you'll have to have something non-empty in your frametitle. Worst case, you can use something invisible if the frame should not have a title.

Comment: I don't think that this saves any writing than the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225588/different-alignment-for-frame-content-in-beamer?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The following new command, `\totop`, should add its content to the top of the frame without interfering with the global frame centering. The only  drawback is choosing the right value by which you `raisebox` that content, I chose `.35\textheight` in the example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern,tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\totop}[1]{\vbox to 0pt{\raisebox{.35\textheight}[\height][0pt]{#1}}\vspace{-\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}{Title}

\totop{%
\begin{tcolorbox}
    align to top
\end{tcolorbox}
}

align to middle

\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

> [image]